# Lambda in Oracle 12.2 Java

Tags: java, oracle, lambda

Using lambda in Oracle 12.2 embedded Java gives error ORA-29536, do not recognize -> symbol. Why? Java version is 1.8.0_271 checked by dbms_java.get_jdk_version. Lambdas are supported in this Java version.

I tried installing Oracle Linux on virtual machine and Oracle 12.2 on it, same result. Here is minimal code I try, it works in Oracle 19 and jdoodle.com with Java 8.

```sql
create or replace and compile java source named lambda_test_min as
public class MyClass2 
{

  interface i_add_function
  {
    String add ( String i_s ) ;
  }
  
  public static void out_call()
  {
    main( null ) ; 
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    i_add_function v_add_function = new i_add_function() 
                                    {
                                      public String add ( String i_s2 ) 
                                      {
                                        return "Added text by anonimous class: " + i_s2 ;
                                      }
                                    };
                                          
    v_add_function = i_s -> "Added text by lambda: " + i_s ;                                          

    System.out.println ( v_add_function.add ( "added text."  ) ) ;
    System.out.println( "java version = " + System.getProperty("java.version") );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm betting the problem is the JDBC driver version for Oracle.  It doesn't matter what version of JDK your code uses if it isn't updated to accept lambdas.  JDK 8 is long past its support life.  You should be using JDK 17.  Upgrade your driver JAR, too.

Comment: @duffymo "*JDK 8 is long past its support life*" Why do people keep saying this here? It's supported for 7 more years.

Comment: @duffymo The OP is using Java embedded within the Oracle database and is **NOT** connecting to the Oracle database via Java and JDBC. Oracle 12.1 comes with Java 6 embedded and supports upgrading to Java 7. I haven't yet found the support matrix for Oracle 12.2 (however, the OP states that their embedded Java version is 1.8.0_271).

Comment: Try putting parentheses around your lambda variable , as in `(i_s) -> ....`

Comment: https://endoflife.date/java.  I would not use this as an argument for staying on JDK 8.  Others can choose as they wish.  I'd only go to production on LTS versions myself.

Comment: @duffymo That is (mostly) irrelevant as you cannot just upgrade the embedded version of Java to any later version. There are a very limited number of versions that you can upgrade to as those are the version supported by the containing database. (However, you can make the argument that the OP should upgrade their database version.)

Comment: @MT0 from Java Developer's Guide for Release 12.2:
1.7 Support for Java 8
Oracle Database 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.1) provides support for Java 8, which enables portability of Java applications and libraries, and compliance with the latest Java standards.

Comment: Yes, that's my argument.  I understand what you're saying.  The mindset that says "I"m fine on JDK8" appears to be affecting the choice of sticking with Oracle 12.2 when the current version is 21.1.0.  I think it's harmful.

Comment: @Robert Harvey No luck. Parentheses or not it's still valid lambda syntax so I had not much expectations anyway :)

Comment: It works in Oracle 18.4.0.0 with Java 1.8.0_161 [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xz5vdhLL).

Comment: @duffymo Migration database to new release is not arbitrary choice. It is large project requiring resources from bussiness. Whole codebase much be tested on same hardware with production workload together with neighboring systems.

Comment: Yes, I get it.  You and your business need to come to grips with the risk you incur by doing nothing.  You are being irresponsible and lazy.  I'm sure the folks who maintain your servers keep up with operating system versions.  The applications that run on them have a similar responsibility to stay current.

Comment: @duffymo Matter here is not in coming to grips, its approval testing budget from bussiness. OS version on servers not changing without testing also. Same for hardware before you ask :)

Comment: They decide how to spend their money.  Your job is to inform them of the risks and keep them up to date.  They will be the ones with the ink dot portrait on the cover of the WSJ if there are problems.

Comment: By the way I found workaround, calling separate JVM using RMI. It works with latest Java 20.